# Arrow function would change the context of this

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

Is it by design that arrow functions can redefine existing functions behavior? Using jQuery's get (yes, I know) - I'm getting two different values of this inside success depending on whether arrow function is used or not. Can anyone explain why it happens?

```
var get = (e) => {
    return new window.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      $.ajax({
        context: {test: 1}, // this
        type: "GET",
        url: "...",
        complete: function () {
          // this is only correct when using old syntax, arrow
          // function would redefine the value of this to the function's parent
        },
        complete: ()=>{ } // Is not working, this is not what I'd expect.
      });
    });
```

Comment: Some 5 minute research about Arrow functions would explain fairly straightforwardly what arrow functions are/do

Answer (score 1):

Arrow functions were *primarily* introduced to change the scoping of `this` which helps to avoid using `.bind(this)` all the time. It's natural that you get different values

From [MDN: Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and **does not bind its own this**, arguments, super, or new.target.

The cleaner, more succint syntax is of secondary value. They are certainly not an absolute replacement for `function`

---

Now that this is taken out of the equation - you've also got 2 `oncomplete` callbacks in your example.

Comment: Exactly.  In the same way you can't just blindly swap every `for` loop for an `Array.forEach`, arrow functions aren't supposed to be a drop in nicer looking function syntax.